# TypeLoadException Encountered in Reshiru.Blazr.IndexedDb.Framework

Tags: c#, blazor, indexeddb

```
Could not resolve type with token 01000034 from typeref (expected class 'Microsoft.JSInterop.DotNetObjectRef' in assembly 'Microsoft.JSInterop, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60')'
```

I am using Reshiru.Blazor.IndexedDb.Framework to use my browser's DB. This is how I implement it:

I created a class:

```
public class ApplicationDb : IndexedDb
    {
        public ApplicationDb(IJSRuntime jSRuntime, string name, int version) : base(jSRuntime, name, version) { }

        public IndexedSet<Incident> Incidents { get; set; }
    }
```

Then created a repository to use this:

```
public class IncidentRepository : IIncidentRepository
{
    private IIndexedDbFactory IndexedDbFactory { get; set; }

    private readonly Task<ApplicationDb> openingDbTask;


    public IncidentRepository(IIndexedDbFactory indexedDbFactory, HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        IndexedDbFactory = indexedDbFactory;
        HttpClient = httpClient;
        openingDbTask = OpenDbAsync();
    }
    
    public async Task<Incident> AddIncident(Incident incident)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = await IndexedDbFactory.Create<ApplicationDb>())
            {
                db.Incidents.Add(incident);
                await db.SaveChanges();
                return incident;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Then added to Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IIndexedDbFactory, IndexedDbFactory>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IIncidentRepository, IncidentRepository>();
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who's still asking, just install this package 'https://github.com/wtulloch/Blazor.IndexedDB'. If you encounter a 'TimeGhost' undefined, just press ctrl+F5.